# Sheafs of abelian groups are the same as $\underline{\mathbb{Z}}$-modules

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

In Vakil's notes page 76, he claims that a sheaf of abelian groups is the same as a $\underline{\mathbb{Z}}$-module, where $\underline{\mathbb{Z}}$ is the constant sheaf associated to $\mathbb{Z}$.

Let $F$ be a sheaf of abelian group over $X$. Given an open set $U\subset X$, we need to find an action

$$\underline{\mathbb{Z}}(U)\times F(U)\to F(U),$$
that is compatible with restriction. Recall that 
$$\underline{\mathbb{Z}}(U) = \{f: U\to \mathbb{Z}: \mathbb{Z} \text{ has discrete topology, $f$ continuous.}\}$$
So how does one define $f\times \alpha\mapsto ?$

I highly doubt the statement is correct. Idealy since an abelian group is a $\mathbb{Z}$-module, don't we want the constant **presheaf** asscoiated to $\mathbb{Z}$ rather than the constant sheaf?

Comment: The statement is correct. The action is by pointwise multiplication.

Comment: The constant presheaf and the constant sheaf are related by a universal property. Use it!

Comment: You send it to the section of $F(U)$ equal to $n\alpha|_{f^{-1}(n)}$ over $f^{-1}(n)$. These glue (the intersections are trivial).

Comment: Possibly related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2069466, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2094400

Comment: See also :https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3373689/360262

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I worked things out and have the following conclusion.

Abelian groups are the same as $\mathbb{Z}$-modules, therefore sheafs of abelian groups are the same as $\underline{\mathbb{Z}}^{pre}$-modules. However, due to the fact that sheafs have the identity and gluability property, this $\underline{\mathbb{Z}}^{pre}$ action can be canonically extended to a $\underline{\mathbb{Z}}$ action, the way [@hoot](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1098613/sheafs-of-abelian-groups-are-the-same-as-underline-mathbbz-modules#comment2241830_1098613) described, where $\underline{\mathbb{Z}}^{pre}$ is identified as the constant functions inside $\underline{\mathbb{Z}}$.

This can also be explained from the adjunction of embedding and sheafification as [@Zhen Lin](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1098613/sheafs-of-abelian-groups-are-the-same-as-underline-mathbbz-modules#comment2239625_1098613) described. The fact that the sheafification of the constant presheaf is the constant sheaf implies that a $\underline{\mathbb{Z}}^{pre}$-module extends uniquely to a $\underline{\mathbb{Z}}$-module.

Answer (score 5):

For some reason this note of Vakil seemed to take a bit for me to unpack -- so once bumping into this question here I felt obligated to include what helped me eventually see the natural structure.

Let's take $\mathscr{F}$ to be a $\underline{\mathbb{Z}}$-module and $U$ some open set in $X$. As @Hoot indirectly mentioned through their comment, it is not hard to see $\mathcal{U}= \{f^{-1}(n)\}_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}$ forms an open cover -- and is arguably the best choice of a cover as $f$ is constant on each element. Since $\mathscr{F}$ is a $\underline{\mathbb{Z}}$-module, we have that for each $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ that

[image]

commutes, hence it follows that

[image]

Using then the property that $\mathscr{F}$ is a sheaf, we can glue together each of the pieces of $f \cdot \alpha$ that are distributed throughout $\{\mathscr{F}(f^{-1}(n))\}_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}$ to get it back.

Neatly being stated: take $\mathcal{U}$ above to be our cover, $f_k = k \cdot \alpha|_{f^{-1}(k)} \in \mathscr{F}(f^{-1}(k))$, and note that for $n,m \in \mathbb{Z}$ that it should be clear we have
\begin{align*}
m=n &\implies f^{-1}(n) \cap f^{-1}(m) = f^{-1}(n) = f^{-1}(m) \\
m \neq n &\implies f^{-1}(n) \cap f^{-1}(m) = \emptyset
\end{align*}
thus in both case we trivially obtain that for all $n,m \in \mathbb{Z}$
$$\text{res}_{f^{-1}(n),f^{-1}(n) \cap f^{-1}(m)} f_n = \text{res}_{f^{-1}(n),f^{-1}(n) \cap f^{-1}(m)} f_m$$
(as recall that $\mathscr{F}(\emptyset)$ is a singleton). Hence by the conclusion of the gluability axiom, we can essentially "glue" our $f_i$'s all together to obtain an $F$ that restricts to each $f_i$ (i.e. we get the existence of such an $F$). The uniqueness of this $F$ follows from the identity axiom on $\mathscr{F}$. This resulting $F$ is what we then define to be $f\cdot \alpha$.

Comment: I was trying to understand this answer but the commutative diagram does not make sense, the cover depends on the element $f$, it cannot be defined for the whole Z(U)

Comment: @GastonBurrull Could you further explain your exact question? Since $f \in \underline{\mathbb{Z}}(U)$, it is a function on all of $U$, so taking the preimage of all integers should provide an open cover for $U$. This is then used to construct the existence and uniqueness of the product $f\cdot \alpha$.

Comment: I am not sure what are you doing, why did you start from the fact that $\mathscr{F}$ is a $\underline{\mathbb{Z}}$-module without having defined the action?