# $\mathscr{F}$ is a sheaf of abelian groups on $X$. Show that $\mathit{Hom}_{\mathit{Ab}_X}(\underline{\mathbb{Z}},\mathscr{F})\cong\mathscr{F}$.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory, abelian-groups, sheaf-theory

This is Exercise 2.3.D. from [Vakil's notes](http://math.stanford.edu/~vakil/216blog/FOAGjun1113public.pdf).

> If $\mathscr{F}$ is a sheaf of abelian groups on $X$. Show that $\mathit{Hom}_{\mathit{Ab}_X}(\underline{\mathbb{Z}},\mathscr{F})\cong\mathscr{F}$.

**Background:**

I just showed $\mathit{Hom}(\underline{\{p\}},\mathscr{F})\cong \mathscr{F}$. I think this should be similar.

**My Attempt:**

$\mathit{Hom}_{\mathit{Ab}_X}(\underline{\mathbb{Z}},\mathscr{F})$ is the collection of data that for any open subset $U\subseteq X$, $\mathit{Hom}_{\mathit{Ab}_X}(\underline{\mathbb{Z}},\mathscr{F})(U)$ is the set of morphisms from $\underline{\mathbb{Z}}|_U$ to $\mathscr{F}|_U$. It suffices to check that $\mathit{Hom}_{\mathit{Ab}_X}(\underline{\mathbb{Z}},\mathscr{F})(U)\cong\mathscr{F}(U)$ for any $U$ as abelian groups. First note that $\mathit{Hom}_{\mathit{Ab}_X}(\underline{\mathbb{Z}},\mathscr{F})(U)$ is an abelian group. It is a set of morphisms $\phi: \underline{\mathbb{Z}}_U\rightarrow \mathscr{F}|_U$ that has is a collection of maps $\phi(V):\underline{\mathbb{Z}}|_U(V)\rightarrow \mathscr{F}|_U(V)$, for each $V\subseteq U$ behaving well with the restriction maps. If $\phi_1,\phi_2\in \mathit{Hom}_{\mathit{Ab}_X}(\underline{\mathbb{Z}},\mathscr{F})(U)$, their addition is defined as $\phi_1+\phi_2$, which is a collection of $(\phi_1+\phi_2)(V)$, such that it sends any $z\in \underline{\mathbb{Z}}|_U(V)$ to $\phi_1(z)+\phi_2(z)$, where $z$ is a locally constant map from $V$ to $\mathbb{Z}$.

**My Question:**

I don't know how to define a map $\sigma: \mathit{Hom}_{\mathit{Ab}_X}(\underline{\mathbb{Z}},\mathscr{F})(U)\rightarrow \mathscr{F}(U)$ which is one-to-one and onto.

For the case $\mathit{Hom}(\underline{\{p\}},\mathscr{F})\cong \mathscr{F}$, there is only one element in ${\{p\}}|_U(V)$. But here it is the integer set.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: The first thing that comes to mind is that a group morphism $\Bbb{Z}\ \longrightarrow\ F$ is uniquely determined by the image of $1\in\Bbb{Z}$, so the argument should be the same as for $\underline{\{p\}}$.

Comment: @Servaes: Thank you for your answer! But is the map $\phi(V):\underline{\mathbb{Z}}|_U(V)\rightarrow \mathscr{F}|_U(V)$ a group homomorphism? If so, shouldn't $1$ be mapped to the identity in $\mathscr{F}|_U(V)$?

Comment: Indeed it is a *group* homomorphism, so $0\in\Bbb{Z}$ gets mapped to $0\in\mathscr{F}|_U(V)$. It isn't a ring homomorphism, so $1$ can go anywhere.

Comment: @Servaes: Ah! I see! Thank you so much!