# For a sheaf with Hausdorff topology, the support of a section is open

Tags: abelian-groups, sheaf-theory

Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a sheaf of abelian groups over a top. space $X$.
Assume also that the sheaf topology is Hausdorff.
Then for a section $s: U \to \mathcal{F}(U)$, its support ${\rm supp}(s) = \{x \in U \mid s(x) \neq 0 \}$ is open in $\mathcal{F}$.

My ideas:

The Hausdorff-condition of a sheaf is equivalent to the "Identity Theorem", meaning if for an open set $V \subset U$ $s \restriction_{V} = 0$, then $s = 0$ on all of $U$. But I don't see how this leads to the support being open.

Comment: Afaik, the Hausdorff condition on the étale space of the sheaf implies the identity principle, but are you sure the converse holds as well? I know that it holds if $X$ is locally connected Hausdorff, but I'm not sure it holds in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\def\sF{\mathcal{F}}
\def\sO{\mathcal{O}}
\def\bbZ{\mathbb{Z}}
\def\sh{\mathsf{Sh}}
\def\ab{\mathsf{Ab}}
\def\supp{\operatorname{supp}}
\def\sB{\mathcal{B}}
$Let $(X,\sO_X)$ be a ringed space and let $\sF$ be a sheaf of $\sO_X$-modules such that the étale space $|\sF|$ is Hausdorff, and let $s\in\sF(U)$ be a section over an open subset $U\subset X$. We are going to show that $\supp s\subset X$ is open (you can verify that if $\sO_X=\underline{\bbZ}$ is the $\bbZ$-constant sheaf on $X$, then the forgetful functor $\sh_{\underline{\bbZ}}(X)\to\sh_{\ab}(X)$ from sheaves of $\underline{\bbZ}$-modules to sheaves of abelian groups is an isomorphism of categories and, hence, your situation is a particular example of the general case. See e.g. [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1098613/sheafs-of-abelian-groups-are-the-same-as-underline-mathbbz-modules) or [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/67709/sheaves-of-mathbb-z-modules-sheaves-of-abelian-groups)).

For any section $t\in\sF(V)$, denote
\begin{align*}
\dot{t}:V&\to|\sF|\\
x&\mapsto t_x
\end{align*}
to the induced continuous section.

Let $x\in\supp s$. Then $s_x\neq 0$. Pick a neighborhood system $\sB$ of $U$ at $x$. Then $\dot{s}(\sB)=\{\dot{s}(B)\mid B\in\sB\}$ and $\dot{0}(\sB)$ are neighborhood systems of $|\sF|$ at $s_x$ and at $0_x$, respectively. Since $|\sF|$ is Hausdorff, there are $B,C\in\sB$ with $\varnothing=\dot{s}(B)\cap\dot{0}(C)=\dot{s}(B\cap C)\cap\dot{0}(B\cap C)$. In particular, $s_y\neq 0_y$ for all $y\in B\cap C$. Thus, $x\in B\cap C\subset\supp s$.

Answer (score 0):

If $s_x \neq 0$ then there is some open set $V$ containing $x$ such that $s
_V \neq 0$. By the identity theorem $s$ is nonzero on every open set inside $V$ and hence $s_y \neq 0$ for each $y \in V$ so $V \subset \mathrm{supp}(\mathcal{F})$ proving that the support is open.

Comment: This argument only works for $X$ locally connected.